# How to use "Multicharts Studies" in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a library project generated by MultiCharts and I dont know how to use that Library to test in Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

I just want to insert a symbol like "GOOG" or "CSCO" ... to display the Chart like this image below.

[image]

But I don't know how to insert symbol. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Give me a reason why you downvote this question???

Answer (score -1):

> I just want to insert a symbol like "GOOG" or "CSCO" ... to display
>   the Chart like this image below.

If you want to change the symbol to one in your example, first right-click on the chart and select 'Format Instruments...':

[image: step 1]

Then choose a data feed (the 'Data Source' pulldown menu in the image below) and a symbol that you want to plot. In the case of your example screenshot, it will be 'GOOG' from the 'Free Quotes' data source.

[image]

Then press 'OK' to display that symbol.

By the way, in the 'Settings' tab in the 'Format Instruments' window (see image above) you can specify a symbol's resolution. In accordance with your example image, you'll need to set it to 1 day.

Comment: I mean input in visual studio, not in MultiCharts

Comment: That's not possible: trading scripts in MultiCharts .NET can only be executed when added to a chart, real-time market scanner, or a strategy in the Portfolio Backtester. You therefore cannot programmatically insert a symbol from Visual Studio without creating a chart first to execute the script on.

Comment: @ANguyen Perhaps you can mark your question as solved? Otherwise, contact MultiCharts directly at http://www.multicharts.com/support/contact/ and hear what they have to say if for some reason you think my answer is not an answer.

Comment: Of course that's not answer. Your solution is to insert symbols directly in MultiCharts.

Comment: Like I said, you cannot insert symbols with the PLStudies project like you want. So the answer is that it isn't possible, unless you first insert a symbol directly in MultiCharts which I showed how to do in my answer. So I'm sorry, but I can't give you the answer you're looking for since it isn't possible what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps the original question needs to be rephrased if the above workaround isn't suitable for you @ANguyen? E.g., "Which trading software allows creating charts programmatically from within Visual Studio?". Probably a SuperUser question.